# Does this functor commute with inverse limits?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, cw-complexes, functors, representable-functor

Let $F$ a contravariant functor from the category $A$ of pointed connected CW-complexes up to homotopy to the category $B$ of pointed sets, with $F$ sending coproducts of $A$ to products of $B$. Let $X_i$ be an ascending series of objects in $A$. Is it true that $F\left(\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}X_i\right) = \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}F(X_i)$, where inverse limit is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit)?

To be more precise I am trying to understand why the following application is defined $F(f) : F(X) \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}F(X_i)$, with $X= \bigcup_{i}X_i$. I was presuming that $f : \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}X_i \to X_i \to X$ and, given that $F$ reverses all the arrows, I would get $F(X) \to F\left(\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}X_i\right)$, but I am not totally sure $F$ commutes with the inverse limit. Is there a different reason why $F(f)$ is defined?

Comment: ```$\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}$``` and ```$\underset{\underset{i\in I}{\longleftarrow}}{\lim}X_i$``` give $\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}$ and $\underset{\underset{i\in I}{\longleftarrow}}{\lim}X_i$ respectively.

Comment: Are you mixing up your direct limits and inverse limits? The space $X = \bigcup_i X_i$ is the direct limit of the $X_i$, not the inverse limit. So a more appropriate questions seems to be whether $F$ carries direct limits to inverse limits.

Comment: @Mathlover alternatively, `\varprojlim` also works for typesetting it

Comment: @PatrickNicodemus no, I am trying to understand if $F\left(\underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}X_i\right) = \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}F(X_i)$ is true and, if it is not, why the application $F(f) : F(X) \to \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}F(X_i)$ is defined

Comment: Ok. The answer is no, $F$ doesn't carry limits to limits. Here's how you get the map: Write $X$ as the direct limit of the $X_j$; and let $i_j$ be the inclusion maps. Then by contravariance $F(X)$ together with the maps $F(i_j):F(X) \to F(X_j)$ form a cone over the $F(X_j)$; by the universal property of the inverse limit, this induces a unique map $F(X) \to\lim_j F(X_j)$.

Comment: Thank you. Is there also a topological reason (taking into account that $X_i$ are CW complexes) why $f$ is defined? I am more than happy with your answer, but I am not very familiar with cones

Comment: The topology comes in here mostly because it's not true for arbitrary spaces that if $X$ is the union of an ascending chain of subspaces, then it is the direct limit of the chain. We need $X$ to have the "Weak topology" with respect to the $X_i$, i.e. $U\subset X$ is open iff its restriction to each $X_i$ is open in the subspace topology. However, if $X$ is a CW complex, and $X_i$ are an ascending chain of subcomplexes (say each $X_i$ is the $i$-dimensional part of $X$) then $X$ will be the direct limit and we can apply the category theory.

Comment: If you are asking for a truly "topological explanation" for the map $f$, none can be given without a description of what $F$ is, as the notion of functor on its own is purely categorical; if $F$ is a cohomology functor or $Hom(\pi_1(-), \pi_1(X))$ then some kind of concrete description of $f$ can be given.

Comment: Thank you :) $F$ is the functor in [Brown theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown%27s_representability_theorem) hypothesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A contravariant functor can -if anything- send *direct* limits to *inverse* limits (this is due to the fact that direct = inverse in the opposite category) or dually inverse limits to direct limits; of course, not every contravariant functor has this property.

Since the terminology "direct" and "inverse" limit is a little bit outdated, let me speak about limits (=inverse, or projective $\varprojlim$) and colimits (=direct, or inductive, $\varinjlim$). Contravariant representable functors send colimits to limits, in the sense that $F(\text{colim})\cong \lim F$, and in general they do not transform limits into colimits, apart in very special cases.

Now, if your spaces $X_i$ are organised as a chain of inclusions

$$ X_0 \subset X_1 \subset X_2 \subset \cdots \subset X_n \subset \cdots X=\text{colim } X_i$$

by applying the contravariant $F$ to this chain one obtains a "opchain"

$$ FX_0 \supset FX_1 \supset FX_2 \supset \cdots \supset FX_n \supset \cdots FX=F\big(\text{colim } X_i\big)$$

The universal property of the limit $\lim X_i$, now, yields a unique map $c : F\big(\text{colim } X_i\big) \to \lim FX_i$. So far, no topology was involved (in the sense that this construction carries over to every category and every functor, provided the co/limits exist), but of course, when this construction is specialised to the/a category of topological spaces, there is a canonical topology on the colimit $X$ in question.

Is it the case that you are interested in this map, and not in a putative $f : \underset{\longleftarrow}{\lim}X_i \to X_i \to X$? It is a very natural question, now, to ask whether $c$ is a bijection, and there are theorems in that direction: as I mentioned, if $F$ is representable, it has this property.

If this is not the case, and you're sure that $f$ is what you want, I will show you that $f$ turns out to be a complicated way to express the CW triple $(X_0, X_i,X)$:

1. first, observe that the object $\varprojlim X_i$ is just homeomorphic to the head of the chain, $X_0$, by virtue of the fact that the limit of a diagram indexed over a category having an initial object coincides with evaluation on said initial object. The chain of spaces in question can be interpreted as a functor from the partially ordered set $\mathbb N = \{0\le 1 \le 2 \le \cdots\}$, and in such category $0$ is an initial object.
2. Given this, there is a canonical choice of a map $X_0 \to X_i$ for $i\ge 0$, the inclusion $X_0 \subseteq X_i$ that composes the first $i$ steps of the chain.
3. Given this, there is also a canonical choice of map $X_i \to X$, since $X$ is the colimit of the chain. Of course, such colimit just amounts to the set-theoretic union $\bigcup X_i$ endowed with the initial topology with respect to the subspaces $X_i$. (This is as far as I would go to say that "there is a topological reason" that defines $f$)
4. All in all, hence, $f$ is the inclusion of $X_0$ in $X_i$, followed by the inclusion of $X_i$ in $X$.

Comment: ...this said, what is the functor $F$ you are applying to the colimit?

Comment: The same old one, a contravariant functor between the said categories $A$ and $B$ satisfying Wedge Axiom and Mayer-Vietoris one. To be more specific, I am talking about the application $i^{*}_{n}$ in Lemma 9.3. on Switzer. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand; in that case yes, representable functors send colimits to limits. As a side remark (and please, don't take me wrong), it seem you're falling into a well-known pitfall of people first-exposed to categorical language; may I suggest a more thorough and organised study of category-theoretic language *before* venturing into this kind of subtleties? It might save you time, and a lot of future frustration... :-)

Comment: For example, have you tried studying *just* category theory for a couple of weeks? Or looking into a more modern book on algebraic topology than Switzer (which has, let's say, a peculiar and Bourbakist approach, opposed to more modern treatment where theorems are clear because they are pictures)? For example, BRT's proof (p. 448) takes exactly 4½ pages in Hatcher. Alternatively, Strom proposes the proof as a series of guided exercises.

Comment: It would be ideal, but for the moment I am just trying to do my best with what I have. I am reading more than one book at once to have a rounder idea. Thank you anyway :)